# Back testing Trading / Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified in R

Tags: r, testing, xts

I applied a different data set to Joshua Ulrich's answer at previous question ([Automatic vlookup and multiply coefficients with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694574/automatic-vlookup-and-multiply-coefficients-with-r)) and it gives an error I haven't been able to solve.

New dataset:Brazil's Bovespa index

(sp<-read.csv("http://www.bolsapt.com/download/historico/%5EBVSP/de-01-01-2000-a-04-02-2013/")

```
spLag <- lag(sp)

Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@JoshuaUlrich used `getSymbols` which returns an `xts` object by default.  `xts` objects are specifically designed to work with time series data.  You're trying to apply the same code to a `data.frame` which is a more general data class.  To create an `xts` object, you must provide a timeBased index.

```
sp.xts <- xts(sp[, 5:9], order.by=as.Date(sp[, 3], format="%Y%m%d"))
spLag <- lag(sp.xts)
```

The above converts the YYYYMMDD column to proper `Date`s and uses that as the index.  Note that all columns of an `xts` object must be of the same class, so I only included numeric columns.

Comment: @Pedro9: if you found this answer helpful, you should up-vote it and/or mark it as the best/accepted answer.  This helps others know your question was answered sufficiently.

Comment: @GSee , do I substitute sp for sp.xts elsewhere? Because it gives me "Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Datelag",(...)length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" afterwards in "> colnames(spLag) <- (...) following @JoshuaUlrich code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich when I clicked the button the first time, it said I needed 15 reputation points. I tried again now and worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pedro9, yes you need to use `sp.xts` elsewhere, or just overwrite it with `sp <- sp.xts` and then use `sp`.  p.s. you should have over 15 rep now. ;)